# What producer collect and convert webserver logs to avro format and write to kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, avro

Current, I want to collect apache web server logs(access_logs, error_logs file) and write to Kafka in Avro format. Is there any existing producer available to do this operation?. If not can you please provide a way to implement it?. I searched on google but no luck.

Like http://grokbase.com/t/kafka/users/14851mg6mk/apache-webserver-access-logs-kafka-producer, but I want to write in Avro format.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [Logstash Kafka output](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-kafka.html) with an [Avro codec](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-codecs-avro.html) - that should do what I understand you want to do.

Comment: Thanks a alot, it's useful to me.